# What should I put in the 'main address' field when applying for a UK transit visa?

Tags: visas, uk, transit

What should I fill for the below question in Visitor on transit form

What is the main address and the contact details of where you will be staying whilst in the UK?

I have no one in UK.. and I am not planning to visit any places in UK, I want to continue my onward journey to Jamaica, where I need to change airports from Gatwick to heathrow and vice versa.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you have the right form?

This is [the application form for the Visitor in Transit visa](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/255349/vaf1h.pdf), and it does not have a box for your address while in the UK, except for applicants under the age of 18.

Answer (score 2):

"Same-day transit between Heathrow and Gatwick" should do nicely then.

Comment: Might be worth explaining why that's acceptable in place of a street address (I get what you mean, but could see why it might not make sense to others)

Comment: does it mean, If I switch the airports on the same day. I do not require any transit visa?

Comment: No, you most likely do need a transit visa if you are changing airports: https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa

Comment: *  


What is the main address and contact details of where you will be staying whilst in the UK? What is the main address and the contact details of where you will be staying whilst in the UK? 


Enter the postcode below and click on 'find address'. 
UK Postcode:  Find Address 

--- Please enter a postcode --- 

Line 1:  *  
Line 2:  
Line 3:  
Line 4:  
Postcode:  
Primary contact no:  *  
Secondary contact no:  
Email:

Comment: I need to fill the above question to get my online application complete.. can I give them the heatrow airport phone number and address.. since I will be taking the connecting flight from there?